# MPAndroidChart - drawing 2 line charts with different number of data points

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I need to draw 2 line charts (in a single chart), but one of those charts has more values (points) than the other. My x-axis labels are, in both cases, strings (representing dates fetched from a MySQL database).

For example, here are two label-value pairs that I need to draw:

```
{"time":"2015-09-08 14:22:27.0","value":"313"},{"time":"2015-09-08 14:22:32.0","value":"294"},{"time":"2015-09-08 14:22:37.0","value":"303"},{"time":"2015-09-08 14:22:41.0","value":"313"},{"time":"2015-09-08 14:22:46.0","value":"365"}
```

.

```
{"time":"2015-09-08 13:00:07.0","value":"245"},{"time":"2015-09-08 13:00:17.0","value":"245"},{"time":"2015-09-08 13:00:27.0","value":"245"},{"time":"2015-09-08 13:00:37.0","value":"245"},{"time":"2015-09-08 13:00:47.0","value":"245"},{"time":"2015-09-08 13:00:57.0","value":"245"},{"time":"2015-09-08 13:01:07.0","value":"245"},{"time":"2015-09-08 14:19:51.0","value":"248"},{"time":"2015-09-08 14:20:01.0","value":"248"},{"time":"2015-09-08 14:20:11.0","value":"248"},{"time":"2015-09-08 14:20:21.0","value":"248"},{"time":"2015-09-08 14:20:31.0","value":"248"},{"time":"2015-09-08 14:20:41.0","value":"248"},{"time":"2015-09-08 14:20:51.0","value":"248"},{"time":"2015-09-08 14:21:00.0","value":"248"},{"time":"2015-09-08 14:21:10.0","value":"248"},{"time":"2015-09-08 14:21:20.0","value":"248"}
```

Now, I have two ArrayLists of strings containing above "time" values (one for each chart), and I need to use them as my x-axis labels when drawing charts. How can I do that with MPAndroidChart?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, unfortunately your question does not demonstrate any attempt of prior research. In order to get a good response, it is advised you should show evidence you have attempted to solve the problem, either in code or otherwise, before asking a question.

Comment: I did research, but couldn't find a useful answer. I assume one way to do what I need would be to somehow join the two sets of "time" values (in the example above), but I don't know how.